# how to Show text at fixed coordinate of (x,y) in Java Script D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new to Java Script d3 library and trying to make a graph using D3 JS I want to show text at particular coordinates of (x,y) but it is showing at top-left corner, not according to where I wanted.

Please anyone can help me out how to show text at particular coordinate of x,y.

**below code** showing text at top-left corner(not showing according to x,y axis) but I want at (2,5) coordinates

How can we find out [x,y] coordinate of the middle point of each path curve where I can show any text. See  here [Path curve](http://jsfiddle.net/365jz5fn/9/)

Here is my running Code [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/365jz5fn/6/)

`

```
 var path0  = [{x: 1.0, y: 8.5},{x: 2.0, y: 5.0}, {x: 1, y: 1.5}];var path1 = [{x: 3, y: 8.5},{x: 4.0, y: 5.0}, {x: 3, y: 1.5}];
  var w = 1200,
      h = 850,
      p = 40,
      x = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 10]).range([p, w - p]),
      y = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 10]).range([h - p, p]);



  var line = d3.svg.line()
            .interpolate("cardinal")
            .x(function(d) { console.log(d);return x(d.x); })
            .y(function(d) { console.log(d); return y(d.y); });



  var vis = d3.select("body").append("svg:svg")
            .attr("width", w)
            .attr("height", h)
            .append("svg:g"); 

  var rules = vis.selectAll("g.rule")
              .data(x.ticks(10))
              .enter().append("svg:g")
              .attr("class", "rule"); 

  rules.append("svg:line")
        .attr("x1", x)
        .attr("x2", x)
        .attr("y1", p)
        .attr("y2", h - p - 1);

  rules.append("svg:line")
        .attr("class", function(d) { return d ? null : "axis"; })
        .attr("y1", y)
        .attr("y2", y)
        .attr("x1", p)
        .attr("x2", w - p + 1);

  rules.append("svg:text")
        .attr("x", x)
        .attr("y", h - p + 3)
        .attr("dy", ".71em")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text(x.tickFormat(10));

  rules.append("svg:text")
        .attr("y", y)
        .attr("x", p - 3)
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .attr("text-anchor", "end")
        .text(y.tickFormat(10)); 

 vis.selectAll("path.path0")
      .data([0])
      .enter().append("svg:path")
      .attr("d", function(d) {  console.log(d);return line.tension(d)(path0); }) 
      .style("stroke","green");



  //it is showing text where I wanted at (241.6,425) coordinates but do not know why it is not taking (2,5) coordinates
  vis.append("text")
        .attr("y", 425)
        .attr("x",241.6)
        .attr("dy", 10)
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text("test1"); 

 //it is showing at top left corner. 
        vis.append("text")
        .attr("x",2)
        .attr("y",5)
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text("test"); 




  vis.selectAll("path.path1")
      .data([0])
      .enter().append("svg:path")
      .attr("d", function(d) {  console.log(d);return line.tension(d)(path1); })
      .style("stroke","green");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While setting a position you are using a pixel based system starting from the top left.

The (2,5) element you refer to are only labels on x and y axis without any other meaning. So D3 will use (2,5) as distance in pixel from the top left...

Note: to avoid incurring in problems you can even work by submultiples of dimension of the chart as here:

```
vis.append("text")
        .attr("x", (w / 2))             
        .attr("y", (h / 2))
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")  
        .style("font-size", "16px") 
        .text("test2");
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/s2yn3b4p/

**Update:**
To align with labels on x and y axis created with:

```
x = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 10]).range([p, w - p]),
y = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 10]).range([h - p, p]);
```

You can make usage of:

```
.attr("y", 5*(h/10))
.attr("x", 2*(w/10))
```

Comment: According to x axis[0-10] and y axis [0-10] I need to show multiple text near [2,5] coordinates how can I do it.you can see here I assumed  x,y coordinates ex: [x,y]=[241.6, 425] print test1 and [241.6,415] print test2 here you can found code(http://jsfiddle.net/365jz5fn/7/) . I want to show text according to label. can we use directly [2,5]  or is there any other way ?

Comment: since you set the boundaries by w & h you can try 5 * (h/10) and 2 * (w /10) to position properly

Comment: If I use x axis[0-20] and y axis [0-20] and dividing w and h by 20 it is not showing exact text at .attr("y", 5*(h/20))
.attr("x", 2*(w/20)). Please check my code (http://jsfiddle.net/365jz5fn/9/). Why did you divide height and width by 10 in previous solution.

Comment: since you defined you chart by getting a range (p, w-p) and applied to it a domain linear scale (0 to 10). So the w,h elements have to be divided by 10  to be correctly scaled. Once you find the basic measure w/10 and h/10 you multiply for 5 to get the height and for 2 to get the width.

Comment: I have changed the it a domain linear scale (0 to 20) and dividing w,h elements by 20 but it is not showing as working for domain linear scale (0 to 10) .Could you please tell me why it is happening. Here is my code (http://jsfiddle.net/365jz5fn/9/).

Comment: i am not able to check the modifications of the fiddle so I modified the one I was already working on http://jsfiddle.net/s2yn3b4p/1/

Comment: I think I should get the x&y coordinate with the help of  mid point of each path curve and show text there. How can we find out the mid point [x,y] coordinate of each path curve?

Answer (score 1):

you can do it two ways either you directly give your points on x and y as text attributes

```
 svg.append("text")
    .attr("x", myXpoint)             
    .attr("y", myypoint)
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")  
    .style("font-size", "16px") 
    .text("any text );
```

or you can add one group element and transform that group element on any point that cover by svg and that case you  x , y will be 0 0  for text attributes and yes also with providing x,y will take position to relative of that group element

```
var textwrapper = svg.append("svg:g")
 .attr("class", "mytext")
 .attr("transform", "translate(" + [x,y] + ")");

 textwrapper.append("text")
    .attr("x", 0)             
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")  
    .style("font-size", "16px") 
    .text("any text );
```

here is advantage over first option is that you can update and animate group element based on your requirement ( we can do it with text also but this way is more smooth and not affect text element properties ) based on some event like mouse hover or info box